# Initialize Flyway data source from persistence.xml

Tags: java, flyway

My application uses persistence.xml to store the DB connection parameters. How can I initialize Flyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyway doesn't support persistence.xml (as of 3.0).

Find a different way to store the DB config (eg, Spring property files) or parse the persistence.xml manually.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to simply read in the XML, extract the values and pass them to `Flyway.setDataSource()`

Comment: That doesn't sound simple at all. Since I use Spring, I've refactored my configs to store the values in property files and inject them where needed. But Flyway should really have better JPA support!

Comment: Well you didn't really mention Spring in the original question :-) Feel free to file an enhancement request in the issue tracker detailing on how you feel JPA support should look like.